# Depth-first search by edge property

Tags: python, boost, graph, graph-tool

I am using graph-tool for python, a library which implements boost.  I need to do a depth-first search using only edges which have the edge_property:

```
rel_need = True
```

So, i'm using

```
gt.dfs_search(g, g.vertex(0), NeedFinder(rel_need, pred, time))
```

with this DFSVisitor:

```
class NeedFinder(gt.DFSVisitor):

    def __init__(self, rel_need, pred, time):
        self.rel_need = rel_need
        self.pred = pred
        self.time = time
        self.last_time = 0

    def discover_vertex(self, u):
        self.time[u] = self.last_time
        self.last_time += 1

    def examine_edge(self, e):
        pass

    def tree_edge(self, e):
        if self.rel_need[e]:
            self.pred[e.target()] = int(e.source())
```

It seems like I should be doing some sort of check in the examine_edge def, but I haven't been able to find docs explaining it.  I have the check in the tree_edge def, which successfully filters all of the rel_need=true edges, but it doesn't change the traversal.  How do I make a DFSVisitor that only traverses certain edges, and not all edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a filtered graph first. You can do:

```
u = GraphView(g, efilt=rel_need)
```

where rel_need is a Boolean property map, where `rel_need[e] == True` means that the edge is not filtered out.

You can then proceed to do the DFS search with the graph `u`, and the edges for which `rel_need[e] == False` will be ignored.